# cannot convert column values into integers: could not convert string to float: 'Inner'

Tags: python, pandas, integer, converters

My input file is under the form:

```
    gold,Program,Requirement,MethodType,Top,Side,CallersT,CallersN,CallersU,CallersCallersT,CallersCallersN,CallersCallersU,CalleesT,CalleesN,CalleesU,CalleesCalleesT,CalleesCalleesN,CalleesCalleesU
T,chess,1,Inner,T,T,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,
N,chess,2,Inner,N,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,
N,chess,3,Inner,N,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,
N,chess,4,Inner,N,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,
N,chess,5,Inner,N,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,
N,chess,6,Inner,N,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,
N,chess,7,Inner,N,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,
N,chess,8,Inner,N,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,
N,chess,1,Inner,NU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,
N,chess,2,Inner,NU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,
N,chess,3,Inner,NU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,
N,chess,4,Root,NU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,
N,chess,5,Inner,NU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,
T,chess,6,Inner,TU,T,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,Medium,High,-1,High,
T,chess,7,Inner,TU,T,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,-1,Medium,High,-1,High,
N,chess,8,Inner,NU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,
N,chess,1,Inner,TNU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,Low,High,Medium,-1,Medium,
N,chess,2,Inner,NU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,Low,Low,Medium,
N,chess,3,Leaf,NU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,-1,Medium,Medium,
T,chess,4,Leaf,NU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,Low,Low,Medium,
N,chess,5,Leaf,NU,N,-1,Low,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,Medium,High,-1,Medium,Medium,
```

Here is the code I am using to convert all the columns having string values into integers. The problem is that my conversion using the line `dataset['MethodType'] = dataset['MethodType'].astype('category').cat.codes` is not working. I cannot convert the `MethodType` column into integers. MethodType has either the values Inner, Leaf or Root and I would like these to be converted to 0, 1 or 2 but I cannot achieve that using the line `dataset['MethodType'] = dataset['MethodType'].astype('category').cat.codes`

```
 import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split



def main():
    X_train={}
    X_test={}
    y_train={}
    y_test={}
    dataset = pd.read_csv( 'dataExtended2.txt', sep= ',') 
    #convert T into 1 and N into 0
    dataset['gold'] = dataset['gold'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['Program'] = dataset['Program'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['Top'] = dataset['Top'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['Side'] = dataset['Side'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['MethodType'] = dataset['MethodType'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersT'] = dataset['CallersT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersN'] = dataset['CallersN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersU'] = dataset['CallersU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersT'] = dataset['CallersCallersT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersN'] = dataset['CallersCallersN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersU'] = dataset['CallersCallersU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesT'] = dataset['CalleesT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesN'] = dataset['CalleesN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesU'] = dataset['CalleesU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesT'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesN'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesU'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesU'].astype('category').cat.codes

    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

    print(dataset.head())
if __name__=="__main__": 
    main()
```

When I execute this code, the MethodType column cannot converted into integers.

Comment: building your DF, method type is a column of strings... build from `T` `N` and so on... how can they be converted...?

Comment: @ItaiBenAmram MethodType has either the values Inner, Leaf or Root and I would like these to be converted to 0, 1 or 2 but I cannot achieve that using the line `dataset['MethodType'] = dataset['MethodType'].astype('category').cat.codes`